# React.js: How to find duplicates for properties in an array of object and put a progressive number on that field

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of object and each object is for example :

```
const myArr=[{name:"john",id:1}{name:"john",id:2}{name:"mary",id:3}]
```

for the first 2 element for the property "name" I have the name "john" that is duplicate.
How can I modify the rendered names like that:

```
const myArr=[{name:"john (1 of 2)",id:1}{name:"john (2 of 2)",id:2}{name:"mary",id:3}]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this helps you

```
const myArr = [{
  name: "john",
  id: 1
}, {
  name: "john",
  id: 2
}, {
  name: "mary",
  id: 3
}]

// to keep a track of current copy index
let nameHash = {}

const newMyArr = myArr.map(ele => {
    const noOccurence = myArr.filter(obj => obj.name ===ele.name).length;
    if(noOccurence > 1){
  // if there are multiple occurences get the current index. If undefined take 1 as first copy index.
    let currentIndex = nameHash[ele.name] || 1;
    const newObj =  {
    name: `${ele.name} (${currentIndex} of ${noOccurence})`,
    id: ele.id
    }
    nameHash[ele.name] = currentIndex+ 1;
    return newObj;
  }
  return ele;
})

console.log(newMyArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the input array into a map by `name` (i.e. group by name property), and map the array of values to the result array. If the group array has more than 1 element in it then sub-map the group to include the numbering. Flatten the overall result.

```js
const myArr = [
  { name: "john", id: 1 },
  { name: "john", id: 2 },
  { name: "mary", id: 3 }
];

const res = Object.values(
  myArr.reduce((groups, current) => {
    if (!groups[current.name]) {
      groups[current.name] = [];
    }
    groups[current.name].push(current);
    return groups;
  }, {})
).flatMap((value) => {
  if (value.length > 1) {
    return value.map((current, i, arr) => ({
      ...current,
      name: `${current.name} (${i + 1} of ${arr.length})`
    }));
  }
  return value;
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do use `reduce()`, `filter()`, and `flat()` and do this:

```js
const myArr = [
  {name:"john", id:1},
  {name:"john", id:2},
  {name:"mary", id:3}
]

const res = Object.values(myArr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const total = myArr.filter(({ name }) => name === curr.name).length;

  if(!acc[curr.name]) {
    acc[curr.name] = [
     {...curr}
    ]
  } else {
    const currentSize = acc[curr.name].length;

    if(currentSize === 1) {
      acc[curr.name][0].name = `${acc[curr.name][0].name} (1 of ${total})`
    }
    
    acc[curr.name].push({
      ...curr,
      name: `${curr.name} (${currentSize + 1} of ${total})`
    })    
  }

  return acc;
}, {})).flat();

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const myArr = [{name:"john",id:1}, {name:"john",id:2}, {name:"mary",id:3}];

const namesArray = myArr.map(elem => elem.name);
const namesTraversed = [];
let currentCountOfName = 1;
let len = 0;

myArr.forEach(elem => {
  len = namesArray.filter(name => name === elem.name).length;
  if (len > 1) {
    if (namesTraversed.includes(elem.name)) {
      namesTraversed.push(elem.name);
      currentCountOfName = namesTraversed.filter(name => name === elem.name).length;
      elem.name = `${elem.name} (${currentCountOfName} of ${len})`;
    } else {
      namesTraversed.push(elem.name);
      currentCountOfName = 1;
      elem.name = `${elem.name} (${currentCountOfName} of ${len})`;
    } 
  }
});

console.log(myArr);
```